# Nothing renders in vue.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

After creating a new Vue project with Vue CLI 3 and deleting all default views and components, I created two new views. None of them appears when changing url and instead I see blank page and no errors in console. In Chrome DevTools inspector I see that `<div id="app"></div>` is empty. Vue.js Devtools plugin doesn't trigger Vue on the page at all. I think I might miss something in my settings but can't find what can cause such behaviour.

This my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

This is my App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

This is index.js of router

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';
import Auth from '../views/Auth.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/auth',
    name: 'auth',
    component: Auth,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  },
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

This is vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('js')
      .use('babel-loader')
      .loader('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        return options;
      });
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `
        @import "@/assets/styles/variables.scss";
        @import "@/assets/styles/global.scss";
        `,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Home.vue:

```
<template>
  <h1>Home page</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'home',
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using vue-cli you shouldn't have vue.config.js populated - as a fresh start -, hence there is a good chance your config is faulty.

Comment: Thank you so much for this hint. I commented the code in vue.config.js and indeed everything was rendered. But I am a bit confused now. How I am supposed to tweak configs for the project if not in `vue.config.js` now?

Comment: You indeed use vue.config.js for extending the basic config they give you.
By default, they will provide you with babel and vue-loader, if they didn't I would see no point in using their cli at all :D https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#global-cli-config This is the guide of what you can extend easily